# How to make lambda expression as a condition in if-then statement

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda

Im quit confused on how to put my lambda expression inside the condition of if-then statement. Or is it possible?  Can you give me an example of this.Thank You!

Comment: It's not clear what you're even trying to achieve. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show existing code where you want to use a lambda expression?

Comment: If you do not provide any code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple example of a lambda function using an if as well as a function taking a lambda as input and using the result in an if-case. Is it either of these you mean?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean ifResult = lambdaIf(
            (pInt) -> { //Call lambdaIf with a function
                if(pInt == 0) { //Our lambda has an if-case for its input
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );

    System.out.println(ifResult);
}

public static boolean lambdaIf(IntPredicate function) {
    if(function.test(0)) { //Evalutate the function and use the result in an if
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes. this is what i am asking for. Thank You so much, such a kind heart. :)